# How to assembly Spark on EC2 t2micro instance (and avoid "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sbt, apache-spark

I'm trying to build Apache Spark on t2micro instance with `sbt/sbt assembly` and it always ends up with an error:

> [error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I've tried various tricks advised online, such as modifying `_JAVA_OPTS` to limit the memory usage, number of parallel threads and also limiting memory for `sbt` command. All this didn't help.

I run Ubuntu 14.04 AMI. I've checked free memory with `free -m` to set up above parameters.

Note: if I use ec2 scripts shipped with Spark distribution and specify t2.micro instance, it works fine.

Comment: please show the values you've put for `-Xmx` that are failing. Note the obvious answer is to use something larger than a micro.

Comment: @tedder42 I've tried various `-Xmx` settings ranging from 128m to 700m, depending on what I've seen in my memory usage report

Comment: Create a swap file on the EBS drive of the micro instance? It won't be fast but it should work...

Comment: Can you include the entire stacktrace of the error? Can you also do `sbt/sbt` and `assembly` inside? If that survives the error, could you do `last assembly` and include the output to the question? That's gonna help narrowing down the issue to the point where an answer could make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.ec2instances.info/  t1.micro has less a Gig of memory.  That's pretty low for Spark (or any Java program).
For Spark I recommend *.medium machines with 4G memory.

Comment: Hi Sujee! Yes, this makes sense. But even if it's a very weak environment for Spark, I should still be able to build it with SBT assembly somehow. Also when I launch t1.micro using Spark EC-2 script - instance are getting set up and Spark runs with no problems. Obviously, I can just switch to more powerful machines, but now it's just interesting to understand. Plus AWS Free Tier allows only micro instances - since I'm on the experimentation stage, it would be very beneficial to practice Spark on EC2 for free

Answer (score 0):

The following link should help
[Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/configuration.html)

It describes how can you adjust memory for executing a program